# FQL fetch all shared links from the day i created facebook account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Facebook graph api explorer. FQL query to get youtube shared videos.

I have following FQL which returns me youtube share for particular account. Instead of fetching all video shares since i created my facebook account is returns only few of them ? i didn't mentioned the date to filter out old records ???? is there a way i can fetch all records from the day i created my facebook account till today ?

```
select created_time,type,description,permalink,message,attachment.name,attachment.caption,attribution 
FROM stream 
where source_id=me() and type=80 and strpos(message,'youtube') >= 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding limit at the end of fql helped.

for example

'LIMIT 5000' will fetch 5000 records and apply filter on it.